# Angular Bootstrap UI modal in controller or directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-controller

I've been using the Angular bootstrap UI modals for a new project

[Modal UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

But for what I have read anytime you manipulate the DOM is better using a Directive instead of a controller,

So. when using a modal or calling a modal aren't you somewhat manipulating the DOM?

Should not that Directives be written for a "directive" instead in a controller? If so, can anyone point to an example?

Thank you

Comment: You're not doing DOM manipulation when showing a modal. You're just invoking a service method returning a promise. That service indirectly does DOM manipulation, but that's none of your business. What matters is that you don't need any DOM to be present when testing your code.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the clarification, i understand now how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

I also use the UI modal. I believe the actual manipulation is not done through your defined controllers but through directives. You can check out the actual code here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal

Comment: Thanks, however take a look at the JS on the link i posted, does that code section in the controller could imply DOM manipulation? or is it totally a good practice, that's my confussion?

Comment: He Danny. That is totally good practice. You're not directly manipulating the DOM :)